# SharePoint: Specific views for each document set

Tags: sharepoint

I am working inside a SharePoint document library with document sets.
Now I wanted to assign specific columns in each document set and therefore have specific metadata for each document set type (there are seven different).

I have already created seven seperate document set content types in the webpage settings and assigned those seven content types inside the document library.

**Content Types**

[image]

Furthermore, I have created seven specific views for each content type and assigned those under 'Folders' in 'In folders of content type' to the specific content type.

***Views***

[image]

However, the view does not change when I switch from one document set to the other.

Can anyone help me with this problem?
I have already read through several articles and these recommend the steps I have already taken.

My second option would be to add seven document libraries to the webpage, instead of seven document sets inside one document library. But I think this is the messier option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while some SharePoint questions are on-topic, this one is not about programming or programmatic use of SharePoint, and so should be asked on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a Document Set content type in library settings one of the options is "Document Set settings".

[image: Screenshot of Link to Document Set Settings]

After you click this link, it will bring up a page to choose allowed nested content types and other advanced settings.  If you scroll to the bottom of this settings page, you will see the options to specify what columns are visible on the Document Set's welcome Page and to `Select View` (which provides a drop-down list of Views you have already configured) to use on that Welcome Page.

[image: Screen shot of View setting on Document Set Settings Page]